# Column as link in APEX 5 IR region

Tags: oracle-apex

I have APEX 5 app and want to create Interactive Report region with pl/sql source. What I want is to have some columns as link to another page. But, when I put in select, for example, `select d_01, ..., '<a href="f?p=MYAPP:105:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.">' || d_26 || '</a>' d_26` I get column d_26 as text `a href="f?` ..., but not value as link.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to unescape special characters of the column. Change **Columns > Security > Escape special characters** property of link column to **No**

Also, you can do this in a declarative way by changing Column Type from Plain Text to Link and then linking it to the desired page.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.

Comment: But, as you suggested, I changed Column Type to Link but I have 31 column in this IR. If I change 26 columns from Plain Text to Link I get error ORA-06502: numeric or value error: character string buffer  too small. So I decided to try using link column in select. If I put only 25 columns to Link everything is fine.

Comment: There is a row length limit with APEX Reports. Usually, if too many columns are selected to be displayed then error ORA-06502 is thrown.

Comment: All right. But how I can display 31 columns, every for one day in month? So I have id column, name column, second name column and 31 days.

Comment: i will be able to troubleshoot if you can build a test instance on apex.oracle.com

Comment: I set up application on apex.oracle.com. Is there a way to set up database, can not run without it?

Comment: yes, you can setup database but there is size limitation (25 MB). try to export your report to .csv and then load data into dummy table @ apex.oracle.com